# Why does grouping ActiveX checkboxes alter OLEObject visibility

Tags: excel, vba, object, checkbox

I have some code that loops through the ActiveX controls on an Excel worksheet. This logs which checkboxes have been selected.

```
Dim obj AS OLEObject
For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(obj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then ' loop through all checkboxes to find selections
        BooCheck = obj.Object
        If BooCheck = True Then
           MyArray(j) = obj.Name 'if checkbox selected then store the associated Name
           j = j + 1
        End If
    End If
Next obj
```

This all works fine. However, as I have a number of checkboxes that I need to move around I thought I'd group them together by Shift/click in design mode, right click and select the "Group" option. However, if I do this the grouped checkboxes vanish from OLEObjects. Where do they go? Is there a way of altering my code to find them when they are grouped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to reference the OLEObjects is like this:

```
Public Sub ReferenceTest(oSheet As Worksheet, sGroupName As String)

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim oOle            As OLEObject

    With oSheet.Shapes.Range(sGroupName).GroupItems
        For i = 1 To .Count
            Set oOle = .Item(i).OLEFormat.Object
            Debug.Print oOle.Name, oOle.Object.Value
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Just specify the sheet and group name, e.g.

```
ReferenceTest ActiveSheet, "Group 1"
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks great! Sorry for being thick, but how do I find out what the Group Name is?

Comment: Doh! Found it in the formula bar!

Comment: One other thing though ... If I group my check boxes the above code works fine. However, if I then group these into a Rectangle then the group is no longer visible. I've tried adding `With osheet.Shapes.Range("Rectangle 54")` around the `With osheet.shapes.range` but no luck so far. Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: You probably need an extra step in the reference. something like `oSheet.Shapes.Range(sGroupName).GroupItems(sSubGroupName).GroupItems`