# VBA How to access all ActiveX controls in a worksheet even the ones within groups

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to access all ActiveX CheckBoxes and OptionButtons in a worksheet. I tried to make a loop for that, but my loop is not able to get all of them.

After checking the names of the ones that I can't get, I found that they are groupped (by selecting them, right click, group). How to access all of my controls in a worksheet even if they are groupped ?

here is the code that I am using now and that allows me to get the controls that are directly in the worksheet not groupped but it is not allowing me to get groupped controls.

I am reading sheets filled by users, and some of the users have groupped the controls and others haven't, that's why I can't really know in advance if controls are groupped or not, so i need to access all of them in current worksheet that my code reads.

```
'ws is my worksheet

Dim obj As OLEObject

For Each obj In ws.OLEObjects
  Debug.Print obj.Name
Next obj
End If
```

Comment: Similar to a question I've asked. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734515/why-does-grouping-activex-checkboxes-alter-oleobject-visibility

Comment: thanks, i am reading now, but don't think it's the same because in your question, you know the names of the groups as it seems and you know if they are groupped or not. while here I can't know the name of groups and I can't know if they are groupped or not, because each users do different things from others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does grouping ActiveX checkboxes alter OLEObject visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734515/why-does-grouping-activex-checkboxes-alter-oleobject-visibility)

Comment: Possible that you didn't read the post or you didn't read my above comment to MiguelH

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an important task to reach all OLE Objects, so I created the below code in a modular fashion and tested on some example objects:

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub Example()
    Dim colOleObjects As Collection: Set colOleObjects = CollectOleObjectsOnWorksheet(ActiveSheet)
    Dim colCheckboxesAndOptionboxes As Collection: Set colCheckboxesAndOptionboxes = FilterOleObjectsByType(colOleObjects, Array("Forms.CheckBox.1", "Forms.OptionButton.1"))
    Dim varItem As Variant: For Each varItem In colCheckboxesAndOptionboxes
        Dim shpItem As Shape: Set shpItem = varItem
        Debug.Print shpItem.Name
    Next varItem
End Sub

Public Function FilterOleObjectsByType(colSource As Collection, varTypes As Variant) As Collection
    Dim colDestination As Collection: Set colDestination = New Collection
    Dim varElement As Variant: For Each varElement In colSource
        Dim shpElement As Shape: Set shpElement = varElement
        Dim i As Long: For i = LBound(varTypes) To UBound(varTypes)
            If shpElement.OLEFormat.progID = varTypes(i) Then
                colDestination.Add shpElement
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next varElement
    Set FilterOleObjectsByType = colDestination
End Function

Public Function CollectOleObjectsOnWorksheet(ewsTarget As Worksheet) As Collection
    Dim colResult As Collection: Set colResult = New Collection
    Dim varChild As Variant: For Each varChild In ewsTarget.Shapes
        Dim shpChild As Shape: Set shpChild = varChild
        Dim colChild As Collection: Set colChild = CollectOleObjectsOfShape(shpChild)
        CollectionAddElements colResult, colChild
    Next varChild
    Set CollectOleObjectsOnWorksheet = colResult
End Function

Public Function CollectOleObjectsOfShape(shpTarget As Shape) As Collection
    Dim colResult As Collection: Set colResult = New Collection
    Select Case shpTarget.Type
    Case MsoShapeType.msoEmbeddedOLEObject, MsoShapeType.msoOLEControlObject
        colResult.Add shpTarget
    Case MsoShapeType.msoGroup
        Dim varChild As Variant: For Each varChild In shpTarget.GroupItems
            Dim shpChild As Shape: Set shpChild = varChild
            Dim colChild As Collection: Set colChild = CollectOleObjectsOfShape(shpChild)
            CollectionAddElements colResult, colChild
        Next varChild
    End Select
    Set CollectOleObjectsOfShape = colResult
End Function

Public Sub CollectionAddElements(colTarget As Collection, colSource As Collection)
    Dim varElement As Variant: For Each varElement In colSource
        colTarget.Add varElement
    Next varElement
End Sub
```

Basically, CollectOleObjectsOnWorksheet returns a collection of all OleObjects on the Worksheet given as a parameter building on the functionality of recursively enumerating OleObjects provided by CollectOleObjectsOfShape. CollectionAddElements is just a helper function to create the union of two Collections. In my code, Example retrieves the Collection of OleObjects on the ActiveSheet, filters it to include only CheckBoxes and OptionBoxes by calling FilterOleObjectsByType then it prints the name of each. However, once you have this collection, you can do anything with it.

I think the advantage of my solution is that the enumeration of objects is decoupled from the actual task you want to do with them. You just have to include the three functions somewhere in the code and call CollectOleObjectsOnWorksheet from your part of the code.

**Update:**

I modified the code: (1) OleObjects may have msoOLEControlObject, (2) I added a Function to filter the objects retrieved, so that they include only CheckBoxes and OptionBoxes.

I would not recommend to Group and Ungroup the Shapes because you can access these objects with my code without modifying the original document. However, if you need to do so, you can call the `.Ungroup` Method of Shape to ungroup them, or the `.Group` Method of ShapeRange. The latter is a bit trickier because you have to call it on an object returned by `Worksheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ShapeName1", "ShapeName2"))` or `Shape.GroupItems.Range(Array("ShapeName1", "ShapeName2"))`.

Comment: Thanks I will check it as well as the answer given below and let you know. By the way, for my current project what I need are checkboxes and optionboxes.
or I ungroup, and I don't save the sheet so it's like if I didn't ungroup

and I was thinking also, is there for example an easy way to ungroup all groups and group them back after code reading ? in this case I ungroup all and group back after i finish and I use my simple code between group and ungroup to get the option and checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

To get all ActiveX Objects, even when put into a group, start by using the `Shapes`-Collection rather than the `OLEObjects`-Collection.

You can check for `Type = msoOLEControlObject` (12) of the shape so that you list only `OLEObjects`. Groups have the Type `msoGroup` (6) and have a Collection `GroupItems` that holds all Shapes within that group.

You could write a recursive routine. See the following code to write all OLEObjects.

**Update**: The code now creates a Dictionary containing all CheckBoxex and RadioButtons plus their value. Note that you need a reference to the Scripting Library.

```
Sub ListAllObjects()
    Dim ListOfOptions as Dictionary
    Set ListOfOptions = New Dictionary

    ListObjects ActiveSheet.Shapes, ListOfOptions
End Sub


Sub ListObjects(objArr, ListOfOptions)
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In objArr
        If sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            ' Debug.Print sh.Name; sh.Type; TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object)
            ' Found OptionButton or CheckBox: Add it to Dictionary.
            If TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = "OptionButton" Or TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
                ListOfOptions.Add sh.Name, sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value
            End If
        End If

        If sh.Type = msoGroup Then
            ListObjects sh.GroupItems, ListOfOptions
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

To **Ungroup**:

```
Dim sh As Shape
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If sh.Type = msoGroup Then sh.Ungroup
Next sh
```

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help, I will give it a try and let you know, but what i want is to get the value of optionbutton and checkboxes so how to access that property in your code ? 
it's a reccursive sub as I can see, am I right or I got something wrong ?

Comment: Yes, it's recursive (so it catches Groups within Groups). I have updated my answer to show how to get CheckBoxes and OptionButtons and their values

Comment: thanks a lot again, I will give it a try as well as the code of z32a7ul, honestly I never thought that getting ole objects may be that complicated. somehow weird design from microsoft, they could have make it easiar to access....by the way, can you read the comment that I said on the other answer ? is there any easy way to ungroup all groups ? if yes I can simply ungroup all, get the object with my simple code above, and i don't save the file so it's like if I didn't ungroup. still don't know if there is a way to ungroup easily

Comment: Added the code to ungroup - this will delete all groups on a sheet as long as they are not nested (yes, it is possible to have groups within groups, in that case the code will fail)

Comment: Thanks, in all workbooks that I saw till now, the users are not having groups inside groups, in this case do you suggest me to use ungroup and then I use my code (the one in the question), or better to directly use your recursive code without the ungroup ?

Comment: I would go for the recursive solution - I hate to modify something that at the end should not be modified. Sooner or later you will do a `Save` that was not planned... At the end it is only a few lines of code. You can even make it more readable by executing 2 loops, one for the OLE-Objects (as you do in your code) and then one to get the groups - there you need the recursive call (don't be afraid of recursion!)